# How to get Null values for more than 1 transaction for an ID IN SQL? Working with two Fact tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to get results by joining two tables using a unique key.

**SUBJECT Table**

| KEY | OCCURS | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YMPRQ72 | 1 | 21 |
| YMPRQJX | 1 | 7 |

**CONSUMER TABLE**

| KEY | TYPE | ITEM_ID | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YMPRQJX | No Charge | 1106 | 0 |
| YMPRQ72 | Deluxe | 20883 | 40 |
| YMPRQJX | Basic | 20889 | 20 |
| YMPRQ72 | No Charge | 1106 | 0 |

**RESULTS**

| KEY | TYPE | ITEM_ID | AMT | OCCURS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YMPRQJX | No Charge | 1106 | 0 | 1 | 7 |
| YMPRQ72 | Deluxe | 20883 | 40 | 1 | 21 |
| YMPRQJX | Basic | 20889 | 20 | 1 | 7 |
| YMPRQ72 | No Charge | 1106 | 0 | 1 | 21 |

You can see in the results for each `Key` `OCCURS` should come only once and same goes with the `Value`. I want to have total of Subjects as 2 because of two unique values but the unique values are matching with multiple values in `TYPE`.

**DESIRED / EXPECTED RESULTS**

| KEY | TYPE | ITEM_ID | AMT | OCCURS | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YMPRQJX | No Charge | 1106 | 0 | - | - |
| YMPRQ72 | Deluxe | 20883 | 40 | 1 | 21 |
| YMPRQJX | Basic | 20889 | 20 | - | - |
| YMPRQ72 | No Charge | 1106 | 0 | 1 | 21 |

CODE I am using for ORACLE database is:

```sql
SELECT c.KEY, c.TYPE, c.ITEM_ID, c.AMT, s.OCCURS, s.VALUE 
FROM CONSUMER c LEFT JOIN SUBJECT s ON c.KEY = s.KEY
```

Comment: How are you choosing which rows get values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate the rows and then a `CASE` expression to put the values on only one row per `KEY`.  It is not clear *which* row you want, just that the last row for the key has the value:

```
SELECT C.KEY, C.TYPE, C.ITEM_ID, C.AMT,
       (CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN S.OCCURS END) as OCCURS, 
       (CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN S.VALUE END) as VALUE
FROM (SELECT C.*,
             ROW_NUMBERI() OVER (PARTITION BY C.KEY ORDER BY NULL) as seqnum
      FROM CONSUMER C 
     ) C LEFT JOIN
     SUBJECT
     ON C.KEY = S.KEY
ORDER BY C.KEY, seqnum DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the values with respect to only "KEY", then it will definitely return all the records on that KEY, because of two unique values but the unique values are matching with multiple values in TYPE as you told, try using join instead of left join:

```
SELECT CONSUMER.KEY, CONSUMER.TYPE, CONSUMER.ITEM_ID, CONSUMER.AMT,
SUBJECT.OCCURS, SUBJECT.VALUE
FROM CONSUMER
JOIN SUBJECT ON CONSUMER.KEY = SUBJECT.KEY;
```

If you want to don't let the KEY repeated and results for each KEY OCCURS should come only once, it could be done by defining the TYPE in WHERE statement as:

```
SELECT CONSUMER.KEY, CONSUMER.TYPE, CONSUMER.ITEM_ID, CONSUMER.AMT,
SUBJECT.OCCURS, SUBJECT.VALUE
FROM CONSUMER
JOIN SUBJECT ON CONSUMER.KEY = SUBJECT.KEY
WHERE CONSUMER.TYPE = "No Charge";
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. @Ramisha- Join did not work, I have already used it.

Comment: @gordan- I understand the approach. I did it using rank but it takes triple amount of time for data with millions of rows. Also- I want both the rows but to show the occurs and value in just one of the Key with duplicates. Any suggestions around that? Thank you